# wordpress buddypress white screen of death

Tags: wordpress

I just got a job of maintaining a wordpress/buddypress site.

I install the site locally with a virtual host, so that I didn't change any cfgs or code.

The site was running ok but today morning when I tries to load it I got white screen without any error in the log or anywhere.

I use a debugger to trace the problem and found the following supper-impressive code (wp-content/plugins/events-and-bookings/lib/class_wd_wpmu_oauth.php:378):

```
private function _refresh_token ($token) {
    $this->set_parameter('refresh_token', $token, self::SCOPE_REFRESH);
    $this->set_header('method', 'POST');

    $raw_token = $this->_refresh_authentication_code();
    if (!$raw_token) die;

    $token_data = json_decode($raw_token, true);
    if (!$token_data) die;

    $token_data['time'] = time();
    if (!isset($token_data['refresh_token'])) $token_data['refresh_token'] = $token;

    $this->set_data('token_data', $token_data);

    return $token_data;
}
```

I comment out the 2 lines that ends with `die;` - and WALLA! problem solved.

My questions are:

1. Why does the code die with out any warning - is it a security thing?
2. is there a better solution than commenting out these lines?
3. did the change I did can cause some unexpected problem that I'm unaware of?
4. what is that code actually doing or any info/reference to this problem.

thanks